# Could not load file or assembly microsoft.hpc.scheduler, Version=2.0.0.0,

Tags: visual-studio, runtime

I am getting this error message, when I try to run any project in visual studio 2008 team system architect edition (On Vista Business 64).

I have couple of third party components installed like DevExpress etc.

I am not using microsoft.hpc.scheduler namespace in this project.

I have installed HPC Pack Client Utilities as suggested by Microsoft Tech Support. But it didn't help either.

Thank you in advance for your help.
- Munawar

Comment: What is the exception's stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to Microsoft.Hpc.Scheduler.dll to your project (If it's not referenced already), and set the reference's `Copy Local` property to `true`.

Comment: SLarks, 
Thanks, but there is nothing related to HPC in this project. This is very simple WinApp. Secondly, I don't have HPC dll avaiable on my machine. Thanks.

Comment: If so, what is trying to use the DLL?

Please post the stack trace.